# Redirection inside call to execvp() not working

Tags: c, exec, fork, io-redirection

I've been implementing a small program that executes a given command using execvp(). It works fine when not using redirection, but when I run a command such as:

```
cat file1.txt > redirected.txt
```

cat outputs the following error messages and fails:

```
cat: >: No such file or directory
cat: redirected.txt: No such file or directory
```

I've done some digging around and I'm starting to think that perhaps execvp() isn't allowed to do redirection because it doesn't run in the shell. Does that mean that I would have to manually pick out when redirection occurs and use pipes in my fork/exec code to get around this restriction? Is there a better way than to use execvp()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Your "small program that executes a given command" is essentially a shell. Since you are writing a shell, it is your job to implement redirections with whatever syntax you desire. The `>` redirection operator is not a feature of the kernel, it is a shell feature.

To implement `sh`-style redirection, you must parse the command, locate the redirection operators, open the files and assign them to input/output descriptors. This must be done *before* calling `execvp`. Look up the `dup2` system call.

Answer (score 9):

You can use system() if you really want to use that sort of syntax.  As you noted, redirection and wildcard expansion and a whole bunch of other things are handled by the shell on Unix-like systems.

The way to do it with fork looks something like this:

```
int kidpid;
int fd = open("redirected.txt", O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT, 0644);
if (fd < 0) { perror("open"); abort(); }
switch (kidpid = fork()) {
  case -1: perror("fork"); abort();
  case 0:
    if (dup2(fd, 1) < 0) { perror("dup2"); abort(); }
    close(fd);
    execvp(cmd, args); perror("execvp"); abort();
  default:
    close(fd);
    /* do whatever the parent wants to do. */
}
```

Comment: You should close `fd` (or _set_ its close-on-exec flag).  As it stands, the process gets an extra open file descriptor.  Not dreadfully harmful here, but could be a problem in other contexts.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Good catch.  I removed the false note at the end, added a close() in the child, and fixed the error-check on dup2().

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the easiest thing to do is:

```
execlp( "/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", "cat file1.txt > redirected.txt", (char *)NULL );
```

You can do the same with `execvp`.

Comment: Might add "exec" right before "cat" in the command to avoid having an extra process.

Comment: The OP's assignment likely requires the use of `execvp` (rather than the high-level `system`) precisely to avoid the use of the shell, for educational purposes. :)