# Stdin redirection in custom shell in C?

Tags: c, shell

So, Basically, I'm creating my own shell in C, which can handle redirection. My stdout redirection is working but my stdin redirection does not work.

I'm trying to redirect stdin for Examples:

```
            hw9> cat < out.txt
            hw9> grep if < out.txt
```

My code:

```
            if(strcmp(token[i],"<")==0)
            {
                token[i]=NULL;
                int fd0;

                if ((fd0 = open(token[i + 1], O_RDONLY)) < 0)
                {
                    perror("Couldn't open input file");
                    exit(0);
                }
                close(0);
                // dup2() copies content of fdo in input of preceeding file
                dup2(fd0, 0); // STDIN_FILENO here can be replaced by 0

                close(fd0); // necessary
            }
```

This is my if block to check and perform stdin redirection but this doesn't seem to work.
The expected output for `cat out.txt`  is `"helloo"` and that should be the same output for `cat < out.txt` because the redirection will correspond to `cat out.txt`. But `cat < out.txt` doesn't give any output. The content of the file `out.txt` is `"helloo"`.

```
hw9> cat out.txt

Tokens:
[0] 'cat'
[1] 'out.txt'
"helloo"
hw9> cat < out.txt

Tokens:
[0] 'cat'
[1] '<'
[2] 'out.txt'
hw9>
```

As you can see, the first call provides the correct output as expected but the second call does not prove any output. 
Let me know if you need any more information. I tried multiple other ways, but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I got it to work! My mistake was calling the `execvp()` outside the if block. I called it inside the if-block, and it seems to work! Thanks guys!

Final code:

```
            if(strcmp(token[i],"<")==0)
            {
                token[i]=NULL;
                int fd0;

                if ((fd0 = open(token[i + 1], O_RDONLY)) < 0)
                {
                    perror("Couldn't open input file");
                    exit(0);
                }
                close(0);
                // dup2() copies content of fdo in input of preceeding file
                dup2(fd0, 0); // STDIN_FILENO here can be replaced by 0
                close(fd0); // necessary
                execvp(*token, token);
                perror("execvp");

            }
```

Comment: See [Redirection inside call to execvp() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784269/redirection-inside-call-to-execvp-not-working) and please provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This question appears to be a duplicate of the first link, but you have not provided enough information to make that determination.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" is not enough to go on.  Note well that an MCVE such as you've been asked for should include a detailed description of the actual observed behavior, and of how that differs from the behavior you want.

Comment: The code looks good save for using 0 instead of STDIN_FILENO. `close(0)` is redundant [and inferior](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html). `dup2` and `close` can fail, although only if arguments are invalid. Can't say anything more, see prev comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543443/in-c-how-do-you-redirect-stdin-stdout-stderr-to-files-when-making-an-execvp-or

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate of the links above because I'm wondering what is wrong with my code rather than trying a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything wrong with your code as far as I can tell. There error probably lies elsewhere, perhaps where you are calling `exec`. For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd0;
    char *args[3] = { NULL };
    args[0] = argv[1];

    if (strcmp(argv[2], "<") == 0) {
        if ((fd0 = open(argv[3], O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
            perror("open");
            exit(1);
        }

        dup2(fd0, STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd0);

        execvp(argv[1], args);

    } else {
        args[1] = argv[2];
        execvp(argv[1], args);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Calling the above `test.out` I see the expected output, calling without redirection,

```
./test.out cat test.c
```

And with redirection (quoted since the shell would do its own redirection)

```
./test.out cat '<' test.c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing where to call `execvp()`. I was calling the `execvp()` outside the `if-else` block which is why it probably not working. It's working now!