# ptracing the patching linux kernel failed

Tags: exec, system-calls, patch, ptrace, execvp

I am trying to ptrace the patching operation with

```
execlp("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", "patch -p1 < patch-2.0.2", (char *)NULL);
```

[Redirection inside call to execvp() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784269/redirection-inside-call-to-execvp-not-working)
But the process is giving me error that there is no such process...

the child process seems to be running but the parent process is not successful in tracing the calls of the child process.

any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: Can you show us the code that the child runs between the fork and the execlp? It (usually) ought to be doing a `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);` somewhere in there.